# When is a bike frame considered too tall?

Tags: bike-fit, tall

I'm currently riding a road bike that feels too short for me. I use it to commute 17 miles per day.

I recently went to a bike shop, and they told me that your ideal frame height is to stand over the bike, lift up the frame, and have no more than a thumb width space below the tire. They also said the frame is measured from the pedal axle to the intersection of the seat post and the cross beam. They said a 57cm frame was probably the best fit for me.

I went home and measured my current bike and it was a few inches smaller. However, I have a few other bikes in my garage in need of repair, and I'm hoping to restore one if it's the right size for me. I measured one and found that it was an inch (~2cm) taller than my goal of a 57cm frame. I was able to stand over the bike with my feet flat on the ground (but the tires were flat).

*I'm wondering if this is an acceptable height. How tall is too tall? What downsides are there when the bike becomes too tall versus too short?*

Comment: When you start singing soprano.  Well, actually, the usual rule is that you can stand flat-footed over the top bar (of a standard diamond frame with horizontal bar) with "comfortable" clearance (an inch or two, in bike shorts).  But fit also depends on the length of your arms and torso -- if your arms or torso are short relative to your legs then you need a shorter frame.  (Exactly how frame size is measured, alas, depends on the person measuring -- there can be about 2" difference depending on the "standard" used.)

Comment: It's not correct that all manufacturers measure their bikes the same way, so don't focus too hard on the measurement listed on the frame. Check out [Sheldon's frame sizing page](http://sheldonbrown.com/frame-sizing.html) for a full explanation of this. The method of straddling and lifting the bike is a good place to start but a thumb width sounds a little close to me. If your bike feels too small, something is probably wrong somewhere. It may be salvageable through moving the seat and/or handlebars though. I'd experiment a bit before trying a whole new bike.

Comment: see http://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/19216/is-it-possible-to-compensate-a-short-sized-frame-by-adjusting-seatpost-and-stem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can go as tall as you like. Have you seen those tall bikes that people must climb up a ladder to use? However practicality is another thing. As the comments have said - enough room to stand-over is a good start. Try getting a bike-fit, adjusting certain geometry (saddle hight, stem etc) may help in your circumstances.